# Solving $y^{(4)}=a^4y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve this differential equation to get 4 basis vectors, where I want them to be $\sin(ax), \cos(ax), \cosh(ax), \sinh(ax)$, but what I do is let $y=e^{xm}$, where $m=a, -a$, twice each, so my four basis vectors are

$$[e^{ax}, e^{-ax}, xe^{ax}, xe^{-ax}].$$

How do I got those other basis vectors?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something has gone wrong, as, e.g., $x e^{ax}$ is not a solution of the given d.e.

Substituting the ansatz
$$y := e^{mx}$$
yields the equation
$$m^4 = a^4;$$
rearranging as $m^4 - a^4 = 0$ and factoring the l.h.s. yields
$$(m - a) (m - ia) (m + a) (m + ia) = 0,$$
and not $(m - a)^2 (m + a)^2 = 0$ (which corresponds to the claimed solutions in which $\pm a$ are each counted twice).

Hint for the remainder: Use the exponential forms of $\sin$, $\cos$, $\sinh$, and $\cosh$.

Comment: Yeah I appear to have made a silly mistake in going too quickly.  So I went and changed $y=e^{iax}=cosx$, $y=e^{-iax}=sinx$, but the hyperbolic answers seem to involve both hyperbolic sines and cosines